# Can I have two ECSlidingViewController Drawer from left and right?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ecslidingviewcontroller, ecslidingviewcontroller-2

I want to have two Drawer menus, one from left another from the right. 
Is it possible using `ECSlidingViewController 2`. If no then can you suggest the better way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this library [RESideMenu](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu) is it very easy and have left and right menus

Here is a sample code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIViewController *firstViewController;// initial view controller
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController]];
    UIViewController *leftMenuViewController; // your left menu
    UIViewController *rightMenuViewController; // your right menu
    RESideMenu *sideMenuViewController = [[RESideMenu alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController
                                                                    leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
                                                                   rightMenuViewController:rightMenuViewController];

    sideMenuViewController.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Stars"];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Offering a link to an alternative library does not answer the question. This would be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: He asked if there is a better way to achieve the same solution

Comment: You're right. Then I recommend including a short example or explaining how he can use RESideMenu to implement this. Answers that only link to a library are usually deleted for being a "link-only answer".

Comment: Ok I'll edit my answer, I just added the link because I'm logging on from my iPhone

Answer (score 0):

You can use **MFSideMenu** too. It is also a very simple library to implement.

The git link is https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu

I have made a video too regarding this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kuhBOTdx00

Here I have set left and central, you can set right side menu too.